# Submit nested forms in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, nested-forms, thymeleaf

I am developing a web application using spring boot, spring mvc and thymeleaf.

I have in template two nested forms with different action and two submit buttons as following:

```
<form name="form1" action="#" th:action="@{/action1}" method="post">
...
     <form name="form2" action="#" th:action="@{/action2}" method="post">
       ...
       <button type="submit" value="Import"/>                           
     </form>
...
<button type="submit" value="Validate"/>    
</form>
```

How to let button "Import" submit form2 not form1...??

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to nest a form in another form if you only ever want to submit one of them?

Comment: Nested forms do not conform to HTML specifications (including HTML5): https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element
If you could explain your use case in a little bit more detail, i.e. what's the difference between action1 and action2 (why can't they just be two separate forms?), we may be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have nested forms because a form can not have another form as descendants. You can have many forms in a body not nested as you know. You can have one set for import and another set for remaining by sharing common backbean.

Please refer the [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)

4.10.3 The form element

Content model:

Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

```
 <body> <form id="outer-form" class="form-horizontal form" th:action="@{/urlOuter}" th:object="${myBackBeanObject}" method="post">
    <fieldset id="form-fieldset">
        <button id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Outer Save</button>
    </fieldset>
 </form>

<form id="inner-form" class="form-horizontal form" th:action="@{/urlInner}" th:object="${myBackBeanObject}" method="post">
    <fieldset id="form-fieldset">
        <button id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">inner Save</button>
    </fieldset>
 </form></body>
```